# xlsx2csv generates empty csv files

Tags: excel, csv

I am trying to convert one excel sheet (the 2nd excel sheet) to csv like this:

```
xlsx2csv datas/excel/product.xlsx -s 2 > datas/excel/products.csv
```

By doing that I get an empty products.csv file. If I ommit the "-s 2" then I get one csv file per sheet, with the sheet name as file name. All also empty.

I have also tried:

```
 xlsx2csv -s 2 datas/excel/product.xlsx datas/excel/products.csv
```

With the same result.
What am I doing wrong?
(note that my system is ubuntu 14)

Comment: What's the output of `file datas/excel/product.xlsx` ?